# Symfony 3 get form errors from @Assert under each fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and I have a simply form mapped on an entity like :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('bank_name', null, ['label' => 'company.bank_name'])
        ->add('bank_address', null, ['label' => 'company.bank_address'])
        ->add('bank_account_name', null, ['label' => 'company.bank_account_name'])
        ->add('bank_iban', null, ['label' => 'company.iban'])
        ->add('bank_bic', null, ['label' => 'company.bic'])
    ;
}
```

In my entity, I have some @Assert validators like :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Iban
 */
private $bankIban;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Bic
 */
private $bankBic;
```

My problem is, in my twig form, @Assert errors are displayed in top of my form, not under each fields (for me it's that).

In my view, if I try with `{{ form_widget(bankForm) }}` or if I try to display each field with `form_row`, I can't have error under each field.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using any kind of `form_theme` ?

Comment: Nop, I'm not... !

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug on a clean symfony 3 project ?

Comment: tried with `{{form(form)}}` too ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add camelcase names to form, like they are in the Entity

```
$builder
 ...
    ->add('bankIban', null, ['label' => 'company.iban'])
    ->add('bankBic', null, ['label' => 'company.bic'])
```